# Why does it take different levels of effort to lift two objects with the same mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, everyday-life, biology

Suppose we have two different objects, one denser than the other.  In short, what I mean is that one object is bigger than the other but they have the same mass. Now why does it take different efforts in raising those two objects to a same height from the same level even though the force required to lift the two objects is same?

The lifting is done on earth itself.

Comment: But does it take different effort? What if the 2 objects have identical shape? Eg, a solid block of wood and a hollow block of steel.

Comment: As the answer below suggests, it might *not* take different efforts at all; it just might *seems* like it, when you have a different shape that is harder to grab and lift. To check if the effort really feels the same or not, you can place the two objects one at a time on a tray and lift the tray. The any effect to to shape, surface, material etc. is eliminated.

Comment: If the lifting is being done on a planet with an atmosphere, then a sufficiently big object for a given mass will lift itself!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the two objects have the same mass, the work done in raising both by a set distance is the same.

However, if a human is the thing doing the lifting, biomechanical efficiency needs to be taken into account. For example, larger objects may require more awkward grips or be held further away from the body, resulting in a longer lever created by the arm and more force exerted on the muscles of the shoulder. This is why it may feel harder to lift a larger or irregularly shaped object.

Answer (score -1):

I like the comment from tfb.  The larger object will experience a larger buoyant force from the atmosphere.

Comment: +1 :-) ..................

Answer (score -3):

Maybe because those same objects are in different places.

If one of them is on earth and the other one on the ISS (International Space Station), lifting them both for the same height will take different efforts.